# Sort Array (DONE) and show original index (HALF INCORRECT?)

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have to sort an array **using a sorting algorithm** and show in which index the values were originally placed. (see expected result vs actual result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YK7BV.png).

I managed to sort correctly the values. BUT the index is HALF correct? Which is confusing me.

```
    public static void sortNumbers(double[] averageNotes) {

        for (int i = 0; i < averageNotes.length; i++) {
            double max = averageNotes[i];
            int maxId = i;

            for (int j = i+1; j < averageNotes.length; j++) {
                if (averageNotes[j] > max) {
                    max = averageNotes[j];
                    maxId = j;

                }
            }
            double temp = averageNotes[i];
            averageNotes[i] = max;
            averageNotes[maxId] = temp;
            System.out.println(averageNotes[i] + " (" + maxId + ")");
        }
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have some restrictions? Can you just create 'int' array of same size where value = index to mirror sorting actions?

Comment: As I see when you swap i element with j, you do not store initial position of i. Try this: [1.2,1.3,1.4, 1.0]

Comment: @TimurEfimov I cannot use Array.sort, I have to use a sorting algorithm (like I just did). I'd be able to solve this using basic java. Yes, what are you proposing should be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an extra array for your indices and sort simultaneously:

```
public static void sortNumbers(double[] averageNotes) {
    //create an array for your indices
    int[] indices = new int[averageNotes.length];

    //fill indices
    for (int i = 0; i < averageNotes.length; i++) {
        indices[i] = i;
    }

    //sort both arrays simultaneously
    for (int i = 0; i < averageNotes.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < averageNotes.length; j++) {
            if (averageNotes[i] < averageNotes[j]) {
                double temp = averageNotes[i];
                averageNotes[i] = averageNotes[j];
                averageNotes[j] = temp;
                
                int t = indices[i];
                indices[i] = indices[j];
                indices[j] = t;
            }
        }
    }

    //print
    for (int i = 0; i < averageNotes.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(averageNotes[i] + " (" + indices[i] + ")");
    }
}
```